# SQL JOIN: WHERE clause and ON clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to figure out how exactly `ON` and `WHERE` work when doing a `JOIN`

My understanding based on other questions is that I should filter in `where` when the condition is on the left side of the join, and in the `on` clause when filtering on the right side

```
select * 
from A 
left join B 
  ON A.something=B.something 
 AND {some_condition_on_B} 
WHERE {some_condition_on_A}
```

I have encountered an issue with a **partitioned** A table

this select is very slow :

```
select * 
from A 
left join B 
  ON A.something=B.something 
WHERE {A.foo = bar}
```

while this makes the query faster:

```
select * 
from A 
left join B 
  ON A.something=B.something 
 AND {A.foo = bar}
WHERE {A.foo = bar}
```

My question is how come the second select is faster ? Is it something I'm missing, because it seems that it shouldn't make a difference

Comment: show the query plans .....

Comment: So everytime you run the slow query it is slow, and everytime you run the fast query it is fast? Or did you run them just once? Once you have run a query, there will be data in caches, so when you run a similar query it may greatly benefit from this and look a lot faster in comparison.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes. the actual queries are more complex, but adding that second condition in the ON clause in one of the CTEs dramatically changes the execution speed (10x faster). I will try to have a minimal example and look the query plans

Answer (score 2):

Don't ask people to explain, ask your PostgreSQL to [`explain`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html): [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/X8Wk6N7D)

```sql
create table A(something text,foo text,some_condition_on_A boolean);
create table B(something text,some_condition_on_B boolean);

explain--why "this select is very slow"
select * from 
A 
left join 
B ON A.something=B.something 
WHERE A.foo = 'bar'
```

| QUERY PLAN |
| --- |
| Hash Right Join (cost=20.93..49.48 rows=27 width=98) |
| Hash Cond: (b.something = a.something) |
| -> Seq Scan on b (cost=0.00..23.30 rows=1330 width=33) |
| -> Hash (cost=20.88..20.88 rows=4 width=65) |
| -> Seq Scan on a (cost=0.00..20.88 rows=4 width=65) |
| Filter: (foo = 'bar'::text) |

```sql
explain--why "this makes the query faster"
select * from 
A 
left join B ON A.something=B.something AND A.foo = 'bar'
WHERE A.foo = 'bar'
```

| QUERY PLAN |
| --- |
| Hash Right Join (cost=20.93..49.55 rows=4 width=98) |
| Hash Cond: (b.something = a.something) |
| Join Filter: (a.foo = 'bar'::text) |
| -> Seq Scan on b (cost=0.00..23.30 rows=1330 width=33) |
| -> Hash (cost=20.88..20.88 rows=4 width=65) |
| -> Seq Scan on a (cost=0.00..20.88 rows=4 width=65) |
| Filter: (foo = 'bar'::text) |

As [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77879518/sql-join-where-clause-and-on-clause/77879842?noredirect=1#comment137298367_77879842) by [@Frank Heikens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/271959/frank-heikens) below, in a real-life scenario on tables that aren't freshly made, empty and without indices, constraints, any stats, prior or ongoing traffic and pretty much anything but column definition, you'd typically want to actually *run* the query and get some more context with [`explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html#id-1.9.3.148.8).

[Query plans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/planner-optimizer.html) heavily depend on the profile of your dataset, your schema and server config, traffic on the table, all of which can change in time and between versions. Anything anyone can tell you about why these queries behave the way they do on *your setup* based on just the statement will be a pretty useless blind guess.

If you instead ask your PostgreSQL to `explain analyze`, it'll tell you ***exactly*** what it did, how and why, based on a very detailed knowledge of everything it depends on.

Comment: Compare that to [how these look if you put some random data in there and add indexes](https://dbfiddle.uk/A08SDLN7) and then [`vacuum analyze` and check again](https://dbfiddle.uk/6qMd7STT).

Comment: Use at least `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` to get the plan + results from execution of the query. A plan is just a plan, and you still know nothing.

Comment: @FrankHeikens Thanks, added that. Main point was that given the limited context laid out by the question, one can only guess or show bare-bones plans on equally bare-bones structure. In the [two demos above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77879518/sql-join-where-clause-and-on-clause/77879842?noredirect=1#comment137297080_77879842) I did add some samples, an index and a more detailed explain to show how incomplete the picture based on just the statements is: the one with `vacuum` even shows opposite "performance". Still, the answer was missing what a real-life `explain` should look like.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from 
A 
left join 
B ON A.something=B.something 
WHERE {A.foo = bar}
```

This joins the tables together and anything which matches A.something = B.something will join. Anything else will have a bunch of null values (more data to be transfered before the final filter)

```
select * from 
A 
left join B ON A.something=B.something AND {A.foo = bar}
WHERE {A.foo = bar}
```

This one joins the tables together, but will result in more null records if nothing was found which matches the condition {A.foo = bar} as well as A.Something = B.something. So less data is being transferred around before we get to the Where condition.

Both at the end are checking if they are equal (a null will never equals what it is being compared against, even another null)

Comment: The query engine would be in error if chose to do the left join before the filter.

Comment: '_less data is being transferred around before we get to the Where condition._' - don't jump to conclusions. The optimizer decides the way it finds the best.